# How to change zoom level of amStockChart programmatically?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I want to change the zoom level of my amStockChart from 1H to 1W through javascript code (without clicking the period selector buttons). I am using amcharts 3 and am not able to find a way to do this. My chart is a normal one like any of the example from amCharts website. Also I am not pasting my chart config here as it will not add any value to the question as this is not config dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
yourChartObject.periodSelector.periods[yourDesiredZoomLevel].button.click();
```

Comment: however I will rely more on @xorspark as he is an SME on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the `selected` property of the period in your periodSelector's `periods` array and call [`setDefaultPeriod`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#setDefaultPeriod) afterward to simulate the click.

```
  chart.periodSelector.periods[0].selected = true;
  chart.periodSelector.setDefaultPeriod();
```

You'll need to unset the selected property of any other previously selected period, of course.